# Is my proof that every group of order 4 is abelian correct?

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, abelian-groups

Prove that every group of order 4 is abelian.

My solution goes like this:

> We consider a group $G=\{e,a_1,a_2,a_3\}$ and a homomorphism from $f:G\longrightarrow \Bbb Z_2\times \Bbb Z_2$ such that $f(e)=(0,0),f(a_1)=(0,1),f(a_2)=(1,0),f(a_3)=(1,1).$ Now, $f$ is a homomorphism indeed as $\forall a,b\in G$, $f(ab)=f(a)+f(b)$ and $f$ is onto and injective due to which it's an isomorphism and hence $G\cong \Bbb Z_2\times \Bbb Z_2 .$ Now, since $ \Bbb Z_2\times \Bbb Z_2 $ is abelian, $G$ is also abelian.

Is the above solution correct? If not, where is it going wrong?

I know there are numerous posts on this topic in this site but I want to verify whether this particular solution can be considered valid or not.

**EDIT: Thank you everyone! I finally got the answer that why this solution is not valid as Mariano Suárez-Álvarez along with many others pointed out. The problem is resolved!**

Comment: There's a mistake somewhere.   While they're both abelian,  there are *two* groups of order $4$.

Comment: If $G=\Bbb Z_4,$ your $f$ isn't a homomorphism.

Comment: But $\Bbb Z_4\not\cong\Bbb Z_2×\Bbb Z_2.$

Comment: Are you familiar with a Cayley table?

Comment: You did not define a homomorphism. You randomly named the nonidentity elements of your group, and there is absolutely no reason for which A1+A2 has to be A3.

Comment: In $Z_4$, your element $a_2$ is (most likely) equal to $a_1 \cdot a_1$, so once you chose where $f$ takes $a_1$, that determines where it must take $a_2$.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez  Thanks! I do get it now!

Comment: Better yet, write an answer yourself making it clear what was wrong with your attempt.

Comment: "onto and surjective"? Maybe I am missing something but onto and surjective are synonyms.

Comment: @Taladris You are right, it should be injective. It's a typo...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the solution given on the post is wrong solely because $f$ is actually not a homomorphism as pointed out by Mariano Suárez-Álvarez in the comment section. That's because when I try to prove $f$ as a homomorphism, it rather becomes a fake-proof because:

> $f(a_1a_2)=f(a_1)+f(a_2),\forall a,b\in G$ must be the condition that must be satisfied in order that $f$ becomes a homomorphism. But we, never know what $a_1a_2$ is actually? It might be $a_3$, might be $e,$ this is where it goes wrong. In the above case, $f(a_1)+f(a_2)=(1,1)$ this is true only if $f(a_1a_2=a_3)=(1,1)$. Although, $f(a_3)=(1,1)$, but $a_1a_2$ might not be $a_3$, it might be $e$ as well. But since $G$ is an arbitary group, we can never conclude or rather assert $a_1a_2=a_3$.

Comment: Looks good! ${}$

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

$\mathbb{Z}_4$ does have a homomorphism going to $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$, but that homomorphism is *not* surjective.

Consider $g$, a generator of $\mathbb{Z}_4$. It has order $4$, but every element of $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ has order $2$, therefore $\{e, g, gg, g^3\}$ must be sent to a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ with cardinality $2$.

---

Here's a proof that every group of order $4$ is Abelian that starts with the assumption that $G$ has order $4$ and works out which group it has to be based on the possible orders of elements.

Suppose we have a group $G$ of order $4$, call its elements $e, a, b, c$.

Suppose $G$ has an element of $4$. Suppose without loss of generality, that $a$ has order $4$, then $G$ is the cyclic group of order $4$ and is Abelian.

Suppose that $G$ does not have an element of order $4$, then $a, b, c$ have order $2$.

Let's consider possible values for $ab$. $ab$ cannot equal $e$ since $a$ is its own inverse. $ab$ cannot equal $a$ because then $b$ would be $e$. $ab$ cannot equal $b$ because then $a$ would be $e$. So $ab$ must equal $c$.

By a similar argument, for any distinct $x$ and $y$ from $\{a, b, c\}$, $xy$ is equal to the $\{a, b, c\} \setminus \{x, y\}$.

Therefore $G$ is $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ and thus Abelian.

Comment: Notice that this is not really an answer, as the question was *what is wrong with my wrong proof?*.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez The part above the horizontal rule is one faulty assumption in the original proof ... that the homomorphism going to $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ is surjective. I guess we're also implicitly making the claim that there's only one group of order $4$ in the original proof, but I don't think that can be fixed without redoing the proof.

Comment: But it is not a homomorphism. That is is not surjective is really the least of its problems :-)

Answer (score 1):

It's not true that $G\cong \Bbb Z_2×\Bbb Z_2$.  $\Bbb Z_4$ has order $4$.  One group is cyclic,  the other isn't.   So they're not isomorphic.

---

If you look into a Cayley table,  you will find that there's only two ways to fill one out for a group of order $4$ (up to relabeling).  Both are symmetric about the diagonal,  meaning both groups are abelian.

There's $16$ squares to fill in.   And every element must appear in each row and column.

---

Alternatively,  either the group is cyclic or it has exponent $2$.

Theorem:  Any group $G$ of exponent $2$ is abelian.

Proof:   $e=(xy)^2=xyxy=xyx^{-1}y^{-1},\forall x,y\in G.$

Answer (score 0):

Without any appeal to orders of elements, Cauchy's Theorem of Lagrange's or type of group: assume that $G$ has $4$ elements and is not abelian. Then we can find two non-identity elements $a,b$ that do not commute, so $ab \neq ba$. Note that this implies $ab \notin \{e,a,b\}$. Because $G$ is closed under the group operation we must have $G=\{e,a,b,ab\}$. Now $ba$ belongs to this set. Since $a$ and $b$ do not commute $ba \notin \{e,a,b\}$. Hence we must have $ab=ba$, a contradiction. So $G$ is abelian after all.